# Linking VS 2008 C++ application

Tags: qgis

I am trying to resolve a few last external link references in my program.

How do I locate the correct libraries for Windows?

I may have incorrect versions of some of my current libraries.  The link errors are:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: shpFOD, Configuration: Release MinDependency Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>ShapePublisher.cpp
1>.\ShapePublisher.cpp(789) : warning C4996: 'QgsMapLayerRegistry::addMapLayer': was declared deprecated
1>        C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\include\qgsmaplayerregistry.h(66) : see declaration of 'QgsMapLayerRegistry::addMapLayer'
1>Linking...
1>libshp.lib(wpoly.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
1>   Creating library ReleaseMinDependency/shpFOD.lib and object ReleaseMinDependency/shpFOD.exp
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsMapLayer::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsMapLayer@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsCoordinateTransform::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsCoordinateTransform@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsMapRenderer::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsMapRenderer@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsVectorLayer::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsVectorLayer@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsApplication::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsApplication@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static bool QgsApplication::mRunningFromBuildDirVERSION_INT" (?mRunningFromBuildDirVERSION_INT@QgsApplication@@0_NA)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class QString QgsApplication::mCfgIntDirVERSION_INT" (?mCfgIntDirVERSION_INT@QgsApplication@@0VQString@@A)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class QString QgsApplication::mBuildSourcePathVERSION_INT" (?mBuildSourcePathVERSION_INT@QgsApplication@@0VQString@@A)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class QString QgsApplication::mBuildOutputPathVERSION_INT" (?mBuildOutputPathVERSION_INT@QgsApplication@@0VQString@@A)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsMapLayerRegistry::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsMapLayerRegistry@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsMapCanvas::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsMapCanvas@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>ShapePublisher.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class QStringList QgsApplication::mGdalSkipListVERSION_INT" (?mGdalSkipListVERSION_INT@QgsApplication@@0VQStringList@@A)
1>.\../bin/Release/shpFOD.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\SGIS\newshpfod\ReleaseMinDependency\BuildLog.htm"
1>shpFOD - 13 error(s), 1 warning(s)
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'shpSetup' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'shpSetup' completed ------
2>------ Build started: Project: shpSetup, Configuration: Release ------
Building file 'C:\SGIS\Setup1\Release\shpSetup.msi'...
WARNING: Unable to create registration information for file named 'mpsuomlib.tlb'
WARNING: Unable to create registration information for file named 'fodmlib.tlb'
ERROR: Could not find file 'c:\SGIS\bin\Release\shpFOD.dll' 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, looks like you either have the wrong version of the QGIS libraries or they just aren't there. Going by the linking errors, this looks like an issue with [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B), which can vary from compiler version to compiler version. It might be that all those libraries were built with a different compiler version, ensure that version of QGIS was built with VS2008 and not MinGW or another version of MSVC.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I think I accidentally reposted the question today a little different way and through close examination I would agree that it could and probably is name mangling.  How can I tell what version of MSVC was used to buid the OSGeo4W complete download install